# Owl api how to get subclass from Reasoner

Tags: java, owl, ontology, owl-api

In protégé when I start the Reasoner some classes get more subclasses from the Reasoner association.... How can I get that in the owl api I try the example but gives me owl: nothing....

Comment: Well, OWL:Nothing *is* a subclass of every class.  But a class may have lots of subclasses.  Is that *only* subclass that you're seeing?  But at any rate, there's not enough information here to help you.  Show your code, your data, the results that you're getting, and what you expected.

Comment: As it stands now, this question is a candidate to be closed, as "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the question is on

You have to use the Hemmit reasoner in order to get the subclass
like this...

```
import org.semanticweb.HermiT.Reasoner;

OWLReasoner reasoner = new Reasoner.ReasonerFactory().createReasoner(ontology);
```

[OWL API Issues](https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/issues/237)

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor sorry you are right I post the code that resolve the problem